# Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't figure out where the issue lies...Based on my research of what this error means, It seems like somewhere I am either sending a request twice or sending a response twice. I don't see anywhere this is happening...

```
file1.js
 export const wrapper = (req, res, next) => {
  async function getValue(user) {
     await getExpiration(user).then(response => {
       if (response.condition) {
         return res.status(401).json()
       } 
     })
   }

   getValue(user)
 }
```

...

```
file2.js

export const getExpiration = async user => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getOrgInfo(user.org_id)
        .then(res => {
          return resolve(res)
        }).catch(err => reject(err))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

...

```
file3.js

// this is a function that talks to my database and returns a promise
export const getOrgInfo = (org_id) => {
return kx('orgs').select('Expiration').where({'id': org_id})
}
```

Comment: It's not likely you'll find the error in these 3 files, it's more likely happen in the main file (`index.js` or `server.js`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error only exists with this new code I'm implementing. Furthermore - it goes away when i delete the line `return res.status(401).json()` out of `file1.js`

Comment: As you said, the error is caused by sending a response twice, by looking at individual files, none of them is sending twice. So it might be the main file that has called `warpper` twice? or something similar, I can't tell until you show the main code.

Comment: We cannot help you until we can see the entire flow of the code for a request that gives you this error from beginning to end, including all asynchronous operations involved.  The error occurs when you attempt to send TWO responses to the same request and is usually caused by improper handling of asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Also, you need to read about the promise anti-pattern of wrapping a promise in another manually created promise.  That's a bad thing to do and you're doing it in file2.js.  Just return the promise you already have.  No need to wrap a new promise around it.

Answer (score 0):

can you try  this:

```
 file1.js
 export const wrapper = async (req, res, next) => {      
     const response = await getExpiration(user);
       if (response.condition) {
         res.status(401).json()
       } else {
         next()
       }       
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. unfortunately, this did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it directly:

```
getOrgInfo(user.org_id).then(response => {
   if (response.condition) {
     return res.status(401).json();
   } 
})
.catch(err => next(err));
```